# Combine multiple sql queries in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So, I've helped a friend with a ticket system for a charity event. On this page users can select the amount of tickets they want and then click on "register". There are no payments involved, they can just register tickets. There are two types of tickets: normal and vip tickets.

I've created three databases: customers, tickets and customer_tickets. Below are the dumps of these tables.

**Customers:**

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `surname` varchar(2056) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(2056) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(2056) NOT NULL,
  `street` varchar(2056) NOT NULL,
  `house` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `postal` varchar(2056) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(2056) NOT NULL,
  `desired_vip_tickets` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `desired_normal_tickets` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `order_id` varchar(2056) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(2056) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=36 ;
```

**Customer_tickets:**

```
CREATE TABLE `customer_tickets` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

**Tickets:**

```
CREATE TABLE `tickets` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ticket_id` varchar(2056) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_type` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `bought` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

When a user clicks register, the code below is executed. However, only the first query is executed and none of the others. Additionally I'm worried if all these queries make the server suffer...

```
$sql = "UPDATE customers SET `status`='$status' WHERE `order_id`='$order_id'";
$qry = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

$sql = "SELECT `desired_vip_tickets`, `desired_normal_tickets` FROM customers WHERE `order_id`='$order_id'";
$qry = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
$array = mysql_fetch_array($qry);

$vip = $array[0];
$normal = $array[1];

$sql = "SELECT `ticket_id` FROM tickets WHERE `ticket_type`='1' AND `bought`='0' LIMIT ".$vip;
$qry = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)) {
    $ticket_id = $row['ticket_id'];

    $ins = "INSERT INTO customer_tickets (`order_id`, `ticket_id`) VALUES ('$order_id', '$ticket_id)";
    $query = mysql_query($ins) or die (mysql_error());

    $upd = "UPDATE tickets SET `bought`='1' WHERE `ticket_id`='$ticket_id";
    $query = mysql_query($upd) or die (mysql_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT ticket_id FROM tickets WHERE `ticket_type`='0' AND `bought`='0' LIMIT ".$normal;
$qry = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)) {
    $ticket_id = $row['ticket_id'];

    $ins = "INSERT INTO customer_tickets (`order_id`, `ticket_id`) VALUES ('$order_id', '$ticket_id)";
    $query = mysql_query($ins) or die (mysql_error());

    $upd = "UPDATE tickets SET `bought`='1' WHERE `ticket_id`='$ticket_id";
    $query = mysql_query($upd) or die (mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: where is `$order_id` coming from?

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot. It's `$order_id = time().$id;`

Comment: and `$id` is coming from? and btw, any sql errors?

Comment: $id is just the customers id in the table, because his credentials are inserted a page before this page.

Comment: This function is too long by any standard. split code in several functions and test each separately.

Comment: do you HAVE $id? seems like you dont. Echo it out and tell me its not empty

Comment: I have `$id`, it's stored in `$_SESSION`.

Comment: What does the id column do in both customer_tickets and tickets?

Comment: Try using different name for different queries (as $sql,$sql1)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to SQL join the different tables. Your sql would have to look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1.customer_name, table2.amount_spent, recentpurchases
WHERE table2.amount_spent = recentpurchases.spendamount
```

I have used example tables for this anser. They are table1, table2 and recentpurchases. Apologies if this was not a helpful answer.